# Oracle UCM - How to clone a site with all the CDF and Data files but name it a new site?

Tags: oracle, oracle-ucm

I have a site with multiple intels in the site hierarchy and now the requirement is to seperate all the intels.

For example: I have a site - GamingInternational.

- GamingInternational

  - US_gaming

    - california
    - Texas
  - uk_gaming

So now the requirement is, I need to split this site intel basis. Or atleast clone it in the same server so that I can delete the other files. Final structure should be :

- Us_Gaming_subIntel

  - US_gaming

    - california
    - Texas

and the other site

- UK_Gaming_subIntel

  - uk_gaming

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this would be a customization.

You could possibly use [this](https://jonathanhult.com/blog/2013/07/delete-content-ridc/) as a baseline to collect the type of data you need. Then, instead of calling a DELETE* service, you would call a CHECKIN* service. Before doing the checkin, you could alter metadata, file names, the project file (where the site name is defined).

Comment: I need to add the whole site. It has more than 5000 pages.